# My IP address is fetching the main page of Stack Overflow with no reason

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer

For some reason my ip address keeps fetching the mainpage of Stack Overflow. I am not doing it myself, I don't really have time refresh so many times to get ~6500 requests.

For now I am blocked from all of the Stack Overflow websites from my own wireless network at home which pretty much sucks.

My ISP says it's not my router gone insane. What else could it be? A virus? I scanned with AVG and there is nothing that is suppoused to cuase such a thing. The only other thing that I can think of is that I black out and start hitting refresh over and over.

I am running Windows XP with FF 3.5.2 or IE 8.

**UPDATE**

Well, problem solved. No reason for that either, I will let you guys know if there is anything new.

Comment: Do you use a proxy server, or an anonymous service? Looks like you go through something that is used by many users, and it's the IP of this intermediate server that is being blocked.

Comment: Maybe you could try to fire up Fiddler or WireShark, to find out whether those reguest are directly from your computer, thus ruling out the proxy. If they are, you can also check User-Client field in those reguest, thou it probably won't help much.

Comment: I often black out and find I've been on SU for hours, you're not alone. Come to a SO Anonymous meeting :P

Comment: @Snark: I neither use a proxy server nor an anonymous service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, problem solved.
No reason for that either,
I will let you guys know if there is anything new.

Answer (score 5):

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) will show open socket connections and the processes that opened them.

Comment: +1 - Good idea, totally forgot about sysinternals

Answer (score 1):

Are you leaving Firefox open on the page? In Firefox theres a tool called "Refresh every" if you right-click on a page and specify the refresh interval.

Comment: There is? Are you sure you're not getting that from an extension?

Comment: I think it was added in 3.5

Comment: FF 3.5.3 in Ubuntu Karmic doesn't have that option in the right-click menu...

Comment: I don't see that option.

Comment: Tab Mix Plus adds that option, as do a few other extensions.

Comment: Nope, I don't have that extension as far as I know :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you hit the `Recent Question Feed` at the bottom right of the page?  That'll "subscribe" the RSS feed to your default RSS reader (can be Firefox itself).

Does your wireless router's status page show any other computers registered?

Comment: Nope. I didn't do anything.